# Implement user interface command with background computing in wpf & mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have some difficulty with implementation user interface commands.
I use wpf, prism and mvvm. My app has two region - main and menu.
While app is loading in the menu region (NavBarControl, Devexpress) registering menu items (NavBarGroup). Each NavBarGroup has some NavBarItem. When a NavBarItem is selected the command which is bound executing. Some commands allow to create an entity. But for that app has to load some data from server and in this time the user interfacу should be responsive. I tried to reach that use next way:

```
this.createAccount.Command = (ICommand)new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteCreateAccount);

private void ExecuteCreateAccount()
    {
        AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, "show", null);
        if (this.isCreateAccountProcessing)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.isCreateAccountProcessing = true;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.AccountListViewModel.LoadUsersCollection()).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(this.ShowAccountEditor);
    }

    private void ShowAccountEditor()
    {
        AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, null, null);
        this.isCreateAccountProcessing = false;

        if (this.createAccount.IsSelected)
        {
            this.AccountListViewModel.CreateNewItem();
        }
    }
```

But maybe there is a better way to rich this goal?
While background computing takes place the app shows loader (AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent). If an user select another menu item the command is considered cancelled and account editor shouldn't be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the DevExpress framework, I suggest you to use the [AsyncCommand](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17354). According to documentation, it designed for the scenarios like you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Prism's `DelegateCommand` can handle `async` tasks. What about this:

```
this.createAccount.Command = (ICommand)new DelegateCommand(this.ExecuteCreateAccount);

private async Task ExecuteCreateAccount()
{
    AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, "show", null);
    if (this.isCreateAccountProcessing)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.isCreateAccountProcessing = true;
    await this.AccountListViewModel.LoadUsersCollection());
    AppEvent.OnShowNotificationEvent(UTNotificationType.ChangeMainLoaderStatus, null, null);
    this.isCreateAccountProcessing = false;

    if (this.createAccount.IsSelected)
    {
        this.AccountListViewModel.CreateNewItem();
    }
}
```

That is, if `AccountListViewModel.LoadUsersCollection()` can be made async. Otherwise you should wrap it in a `Task.Run` like this

```
await Task.Run( () => this.AccountListViewModel.LoadUsersCollection() );
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems likewise from my case.

Comment: The difference is that in the question, you use the task in a fire-and-forget-style, at least exception-wise. But, of course, all solutions for this will look similar, as there's an obvious method for solving the problem of calling an sync api in an async way. `async` / `await` looks more fluent than the likes of TPL's `ContinueWith`, though...